# Jquery UI droppable propagates on overlapping floated sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm writing an app that let's you drag elements from a column on the right, and drop them on a column on the left, and once you drop them the dragged element (a clone of it) is appended to the element where it's dropped. You can also drag and drop a class that floats the element (basically you can float the elements).

The problem is that when you drop two elements on the same container, that is: you make two siblings, and then float one of them, **every new element you add to the floated element is also added to the overlapping sibling.**

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5265cg7a/11/

```
$(function() {




function droppingFunc(event, ui) {


    if (ui.helper.hasClass("add-elem")) {
      event.stopPropagation();
       $(event.target)
        .append($(ui.draggable.clone().addClass("testing someHeight someMargin clearFix"))
          .clone()
          .html("")
          .droppable({
            drop: droppingFunc,
            greedy: true,
            tolerance: "pointer"
          })
        );

    } else if (ui.helper.hasClass("add-class")) {
      var classToAdd = ui.helper.attr("title");
      $(this)
        .addClass(classToAdd);
    }
  }


  $(".drag-elem").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
  });
  $(".drop-elem").droppable({
    drop: droppingFunc,
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: "pointer"
  });


});
```

Do the follwing and you´ll se the bug:

1. Add two siblings by dragging two times the "Add an element" button from the right column and dropping it on the left area.
2. Float one of them by dragging the "Float an element" button and dropping it in one of the previously created elements.
3. **Add a new child element to the floated sibling. You'll see that a new child element is simultaneously added to the overlapping sibling.**

Obviously what i want is that the dropped element only gets added to the element where its being dropped and not to any siblings.

I look forward to all your answers and i thank you in advance for all the help!!

Comment: On step 3, the element doesn't have a class of `left`, when it's added.

Comment: It should'nt have the class "left" because you only add an element. The class ""left" only floats the element to the left. You have to drag the "left" button into an element to add the class "left". The problem arises when you add an element to a floated element that has a sibling overlapping. If they don´t overlap it works like a charm. The problems are: they are siblings (event.stopPropagation won´t work) and both have position:static (checking z-index won´t work either, and i can´t change to position: relative an add different z-index for all the elements; that´s not an option).